# Options to refinish deck

Tags: deck, waterproofing, sealing, staining, seal

Our wood deck is only a few years old, and has taken quite a beating from the weather. We just moved in, and I'm not sure if the previous owners have taken care of it properly.

On our old house's wooden deck, every two years I would powerwash and sand it down, and then seal with Thompson's clear water seal or something similar.

This new deck has been treated with Behr DeckPlus Solid Color Waterproofing Woodstain. It says it should last five years, but it clearly hasn't.

What's my best option to prep the deck? Same thing as before powerwash and sand, then let it dry out?

What are some options to seal it? Are there any products that produce almost a vinyl-like coating, effectively turning the wood deck into something similar to a composite?

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you what I did with my deck and it worked great... The product name is Copper Green-Brown

Copper-Green    1 gal. Wood Preservative
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Copper-Green-1-gal-Wood-Preservative-221832/300502828

I just retreat it every 3 years ( no stripping needed ) and it looks fantastic. Very simple solution

Comment: Does your deck take a lot of sun?

Comment: Part of it , yes.